# How do I invoke the debugger in a Rails functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

With Rails 3, Ruby 1.9, and Test::Unit, what's the right way to invoke the debugger on a functional test? I've tried adding "debugger" and then running rake:test:functionals:

```
class AdminControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    test "should get index" do
        debugger
        get :index
        assert_redirected_to welcome_url
    end
end
```

but Ruby seems to ignore the call to debugger (the test goes ahead and runs normally). If I try running the test directly:

```
ruby -r debug test/functional/admin_controller_test.rb
```

then Ruby can't find test_helper.rb.  If, following the answer below, I run:

```
ruby -I "lib:test" test/functional/admin_controller_test.rb
```

then it finds test_helper but again runs the test to completion without invoking the debugger. My Gemfile does have:

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug', :group => :development
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've always been able to debug tests using just:

```
ruby -I"lib:test" test/functional/admin_controller_test.rb
```

I've got the following in my .rdebugrc file, if it helps:

```
set autolist
set autoeval
set autoreload
set forcestep
```

Comment: Nope, that's not launching the debugger for me; the test runs to completion, even after adding those lines to .rdebugrc.

Comment: But you can debug your app, just not the tests? Is your "gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'" included in your :test group as well as :development?

Comment: bing bing bing! I had the ruby-debug19 only in the :development group.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm getting `require: no such file to load -- test/functional/../test_helper (LoadError)`

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need the `ruby-debug19` gem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and fixed it by adding 'debugger' to the test group in my Gemfile.

Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem "debugger"
end
```

Command:

```
bundle exec ruby -Itest test/unit/user_test.rb -n test_the_truth
```